# written in, written on, written to the file

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context, prepositions

Which one is grammatically correct?

1. The statement is written on the file.
2. The statement is written in the file.
3. The statement is/was written to the file.

I should mention that I am talking about a computer file, just in case you need more context.

Thank you.

Comment: All are grammatically correct. As are *after, between, inside, before, out from behind*, or indeed any preposition at all. They mean different things, however.

Comment: "Written to" is commonly used.  "Written in" may be used occasionally, when the discussion centers around a detail in the file, vs, in essence, the entire file.  "Written on" would be relatively rare.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In computing, the preposition "to" is used for files. I can't think of a programming function that uses the word in this context off the top of my head, but I know that programming documentation uses "to".

Here is an [extract from MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hxwfzt61.aspx):

> This example opens a StreamWriter object with the My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter method and uses it to **write a string to a text file** with the WriteLine method of the StreamWriter class.

Comment: That is why I am confused. So, you suggest that since I am talking about computing, I should use sentence number 3?

Comment: @ChristianJaimes Correct